# Making rosnode_cleanup() not wait for y/n from user

Tags: ros-melodic, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I arrived at [rosnode_cleanup()](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/rosnode/html/rosnode-pysrc.html#rosnode_cleanup) after looking at [#q9521](https://answers.ros.org/question/9521/rosnode-zombies/) and [#q285530](https://answers.ros.org/question/285530/abnormal-exited-rosnode-still-be-seen-on-master/).

I need to use `rosnode.rosnode_cleanup()` in my Python script, but it is blocking because it **waits for yes/no confirmation from user**. While I understand this was put there for good reasons, for my purposes I need to make it non-blocking.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Looking at the source code, probably not? Is there another way to get the equivalent functionality without re-implementing most of `rosnode` myself?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400885/making-rosnode_cleanup()-not-wait-for-y/n-from-user/) by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on ROS Answers with karma: 228 on 2022-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Technically, you could *probably* hack around this by injecting characters into `stdin` in some way.

But I would not recommend you do that.

The main thing is: `rosnode_cleanup()` implements a TUI (text-bsed user interface). It's not meant to be reused as a vanilla function in a library.

If you want to reuse the main functionality, you'd have to call `cleanup_master_blacklist(..)` with the required arguments directly.

> Is there another way to get the equivalent functionality without re-implementing most of `rosnode` myself?

I'm not sure what you're asking here.

`rosnode_cleanup()` essentially does this:

```
pinged, unpinged = rosnode_ping_all()
if unpinged:
    master = rosgraph.Master(ID)
    cleanup_master_blacklist(master, unpinged)
```

the rest is all just handling user input + output.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abhishek47](https://answers.ros.org/users/34260/abhishek47/) on 2022-05-21**:
Thanks for the answer.

> Is there another way to get the equivalent functionality without re-implementing most of rosnode myself?

Yeah I realize now simply importing `rosnode_ping_all()` and `cleanup_master_blacklist()` should be all I need.